# Return contents of geometry() as a list in PySide

Tags: python-3.x, pyside, qrect

I'm currently writing an application in PySide, and I want it to save the window dimensions upon exiting.  The `geometry()` method retuns something like `PySide.QtCore.QRect(300, 300, 550, 150)` but all I want is `(300, 300, 550, 150)`.  I could find a way to parse it, but I want a cleaner method.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleaner way, without any parsing, would be to use `QSettings` to store and retrieve the `QRect` returned by geometry to/from the native application settings storage (Windows registry, .ini file, .plist file...).

For example:

```
settings = QSettings(...);    
settings.setValue("lastGeometry", self.geometry())

# and to retrieve the value
lastGeometry = settings.value("lastGeometry")
if lastGeometry.isValid():
    self.setGeometry(lastGeometry)
```

You can also binary serialize or deserialize a `QRect` with `QDataStream` to a 16 byte array representing the 4 32-bit integers.

Comment: I'm trying to make this application cross-platform, but mainly it has to work on Linux, so would this still be feasible?  Would this have any advantage over saving the tuple returned from getRect() to a text file instead?

Comment: The main advantage is that, if you set the `applicationName` and `organizationName` properties in you `QApplication` object,  your configuration will be automatically stored at the [platform standard location](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#locations-where-application-settings-are-stored) for configuration data, so you don't have to write any platform specific code for that part. You have also type safety, concurrent access from multiple process, and you can store most of [the Qt value types supported by `QVariant`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#Type-enum).

Comment: I think I might actually use this instead.  Currently I have to store each number in the tuple as a separate variable, because ConfigParser reads the tuple as a string.

Answer (score 5):

The [getRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrect.html#getRect) method returns a tuple of the values:

```
>>> widget.geometry().getRect()
(0, 0, 640, 480)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll use this method unless alexisdm gives me a good reason to use his instead.

Answer (score 1):

Considering OP has accepted the one from @alexisdm this might be interesting:

I was looking into using `restoreGeometry()` as it handles recovering outside of screen windows and ones that are out of the top border. BUT: it **needs** a QByteArray and I can only save plain Python data in my case. So I tried to turn the byte array into a string:

```
encoded = str(self.saveGeometry().toPercentEncoding())
print('encoded: %s' % encoded)
>>> encoded: %01%D9%D0%CB%00%01%00%00%FF%F...

geometry = QtCore.QByteArray().fromPercentEncoding(encoded)
self.restoreGeometry(geometry)
```

Voilà!